# This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server in IE 11

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Eclipse\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");


}
```

IE Version- 11

Selenium- 2.39

Java - 1.8

Internet explorer is launching but displaying "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server" on GUI and not launching the mentioned website in get method. 
Kindly confirm if these versions are compatible with another or not.
I have set "Enabled Protected Mode" at the same level.

Comment: Can you get the IE driver from this page and check https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069

Answer (score 0):

if you have only blank page without navigating to URL means not using updated jars or Driver.exe files or both.

Take latest http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and try.